# Movie Id Where Hacker Has No Monitor

Tags: story-identification, movie, artificial-intelligence, computers

I remember seeing a movie when in the late 90s on basic television that was about some sort of AI or computer virus that was taking over. It may have been hurting/killing people via their monitors somehow.

The only scene I really remember is that there was this stereotypical, fat, dirty, hacker guy they tried to go to for help. The reason they went to him, aside from his supposedly mythical hacking abilities, was that he was so good he didn't need to use a monitor. The protagonists reasoned this would make him immune from attack by the AI/virus. Unfortunately, the AI/virus figured out he didn't have a monitor and sent an electric shock through his keyboard that killed him.

Unfortunately, that's all I can remember of the movie.

Answer (score 3):

Might this be *Ghost in the Machine* (1993)?

> After Terry (Karen Allen) tells a computer store clerk where she lives, the information falls into the hands of the clerk's co-worker Karl (Ted Marcoux), the serial murderer known as the "Address Book Killer." When Karl is injured in a car crash, his doctors place him in an MRI machine. As Karl dies, the computer powering the machine extracts his soul. The murderous computer system then locates Terry and tries to kill her by turning technological devices into deadly weapons.

Comment: It might be. I'll watch it this weekend and report back.

Comment: @TomPridham so did you ever get a chance to confirm whether this was the right movie?

Comment: @TomPridham, did you watch the movie?

Comment: this was not the movie i remember